# Difference between number of modes and number of states

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If we look, e.g. at the [Debye model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model), we can calculate the number of modes by summing over all wave vectors and multiplying with $3$ for the longitudinal and transversal modes:

$$\#\mathrm{modes}=3\sum_\vec{k}$$

Is the number of states just $\sum_\vec{k}$ which would make more sense, or do we include the factor $3$ also in the number of states?

Comment: Why would $\sum_\vec{k}$ make more sense for the number of states?

Comment: @Andrew because we are labelling the states with $\vec{k}$ and the factor 3 comes just from the orientation of the mode.

Comment: Consider a solid with a compression wave traveling in the $x$ direction, and a solid with a transverse wave traveling in the $x$ direction. I'd consider those to be two different states, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Andrew different of course but the waves have the same quantum numbers if the solid is homogeneous. So you would say that there is no difference between number of modes and number of states?

Comment: Yes, I would say number of (single particle) states and number of modes is equivalent. And I don't agree about the quantum numbers. Polarization is a valid quantum number, in addition to $\vec{k}$.

Comment: But the fact that you said "of course different" makes me think you *do* recognize there is a physical distinction between a compressional wave and a transverse wave with wavevector $\vec{k}$ (and between the two types of transverse waves). Don't be confused by the formalism; the formalism *has* to capture this physical difference if it is to be any good. Always use physics as a guide, not math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a system of $N$ particles in 3D, the normal modes are a set of collective coordinates in a bijective correspondence with the original $3N$ scalar coordinates.

For simplicity, let's consider a crystalline solid with one atom per cell. The case of more than one atom per cell is a trivial generalization. The number of possible wavevectors ${\bf k}$ is $N$. This implies that labeling the normal modes with wavevectors only cannot be a bijective correspondence. We need an additional label, and, taking into account the physical meaning of a normal mode as a collective vibrational movement with the same frequency, we can introduce a *polarization* index $s$.

Therefore, a sum over the normal modes should be indicated as $\sum_{{\bf k},s}$. Suppose, like in the Debye model, we are summing over the states a function independent of the polarization. In that case, we only get a sum over the wavenumbers multiplied by a factor of $3$.

Comment: So is it always the case that the number of modes equals the number of states?

Comment: @Silas Yes. It must be so because normal modes are just a change of variables used to describe *the same* dynamics. It must be invertible.

Comment: With change of variable you mean that we switch from the eigenstates of each individual harmonic oscillator to the eigenstates (modes) of the collective field?

Comment: @Silas No, there is no individual harmonic oscillator (that would be Einstein's model). I mean that we switch from the variables describing the positions of individual atoms to the eigenstate of the dynamical matrix (the normal modes).

Comment: Thanks! But I thought of this as having $3N$ independent $1$ dimensional harmonic oscillators where we describe each mode individual and then switching on the interactions which gives us collective eigenmodes. Is this also valid?

Comment: @Silas If we have independent harmonic oscillators, there is no reason to use normal modes. Normal modes transform the original 3N *coupled* equations of motion of 3N not-independent oscillators into an equivalent set of equations of motion for 3N independent *collective* oscillators.